# Apple Script to refresh safari at intervals and then to run key codes at interval

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to incorporate following tasks.

1. Refresh Safari every 10 minutes
2. After every refresh, press down and right arrow at specific intervals.

**Question**: I'm not sure how to put both pieces together.

**Code related to #1**

```
-- Function to refresh Safari
on refreshSafari()
    tell application "Safari"
        tell front window
            do JavaScript "location.reload();" in current tab
        end tell
    end tell
end refreshSafari

-- Call the refresh function
refreshSafari()
```

**Code related to #2**

```
repeat
    tell application "Safari"
        activate
    end tell
    
    delay 2
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 125
    end tell
    
    delay 3
    
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 124
    end tell
end repeat
```

---

**My Attempt**

I refactored to use following code but it's not working.
The `refreshSafari` gets called once but doesn't get called again.
`simulateRightArrowKeyPress` works fine as expected.

```
-- Function to simulate the right arrow key press
on simulateRightArrowKeyPress()
    repeat
        tell application "Safari"
            activate
        end tell
        
        delay 2
        
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 125
        end tell
        
        delay 3
        
        tell application "System Events"
            key code 124
        end tell
    end repeat
end simulateRightArrowKeyPress

-- Function to refresh Safari
on refreshSafari()
    tell application "Safari"
        tell front window
            do JavaScript "location.reload();" in current tab
        end tell
    end tell
end refreshSafari

-- Function to run the combined task
on runScheduledTask()
    repeat
        refreshSafari()
        simulateRightArrowKeyPress()
        delay (1 * 60) -- x minutes in seconds      
    end repeat
end runScheduledTask

-- Call the function to run the combined task
runScheduledTask()
```